# How to call this java library in clojure

Tags: clojure, plivo

I'm trying to translate this java code into clojure:

```
package com.plivo.api.samples.message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

import com.plivo.api.Plivo;
import com.plivo.api.exceptions.PlivoRestException;
import com.plivo.api.models.message.Message;
import com.plivo.api.models.message.MessageCreateResponse;

/**
* Example for Message create
*/
class MessageCreate {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Plivo.init();
        try {
            MessageCreateResponse response = Message.creator("14153336666", Collections.singletonList("14156667777"), "Test Message")
                .create();

            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (PlivoRestException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even care about the error checking, I can't figure out how to get my code to run this line:

```
Message.creator("14153336666", Collections.singletonList("14156667777"), "Test Message")
                    .create();
```

I've imported the correct dependencies into my project.clj, I just don't know ho to do the java interop in a way where creator is recognized. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post any Clojure code you've written to try to solve the problem, but the calling convention is probably something like this:

```
(let [creator (Message/creator "14153336666"
                               (Collections/singletonList "14156667777")
                               "Test Message")]
  (.create creator))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was calling the arguments in the wrong place I now see. Here is what I was doing:
(defn call-plivo! [dst-phone message]
  (.create (Message/creator)
           (config/env :our-number)
           (.singletonList Collections dst-phone)
           message))
Thank you! I really don't know how to read Java code.